# CSS calc() not working in wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4

Tags: css, qt, wkhtmltopdf

I am using `wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4` (with patched qt) *(with node js)* to generate my preview pdf of a html.

**This works perfectly**

```
<div style="width: 20%;);>
   Test Element
</div>
```

**But this doesn't in wkhtmltopdf (this works well in other browsers)**

```
<div style="width: calc(100% / 5);width: -webkit-calc(100% / 5);>
   Test Element
</div>
```

Is there any work around for css3 `calc()` function?
Is it supported to my `wkhtmltopdf` version?

Comment: By the way, why you are not using `width: 20%;` instead of `calc()`..?

Comment: the number of elements are not fixed in one line, some times its 2..3..4 or 10..
if elements are 8 .then that case width: calc(100% / 8)
if I want to use width: 20%; I'll use it in CSS file instead of inline css!

Comment: as far as I know `calc()`is not CSS3 standard, but an experimental function!?

Comment: thanks @xander, I was not aware of this,
 is there any work around in my case?

Comment: It depends on how do you generate the HTML string I guess, or where is it coming from? if you can't influence the HTML generation you can still do a simple replace of `calc(100% / 5)` with `20%` with a RegEx loop or something maybe?

Comment: @xander It is technically a "Candidate Recommendation"; however, it's been supported by every major browser for a long time. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

This is far from bleeding edge css.  That's more for things like variables. Which even then works in every desktop browser but IE

Comment: @Chandrakant If you are work in php then you can first calculate value in php. Then that value used in css dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `flex` property. I have considered that there should be minimum 2 `div` each with `width:50%`. if you will add more `div's` with the same width in `flexRow` it will adjust.if there is the possibility of single `div` in a row then update `flexChild width` to `100%`. it works perfectly well.

```css
.flexRow{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  padding:15px;
  background-color:red;
  height:100px;
}
.flexChild{
  display:block;
  background-color:#000;
  width:50%;
  border:1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexRow">
  <div class="flexChild"></div>
  <div class="flexChild"></div>
  <div class="flexChild"></div>
  <div class="flexChild"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this flex thing will not work for me

there are some more inline css calculations to deal with .. something like left: calc((100% / 5 / 2) - 11px)..

Answer (score 0):

I use SCSS for my project and what seems to be working is to let it do the math inside another variable like this (using functions as well), which works both in HTML page and rendered WKHTMLTOPDF report:

```scss
$line-height: 1.5;
$font-size: 1rem;

@function min-lines-height($lines) {
    @return $font-size * $line-height * $lines;
}

.two-lines {
  min-height: min-lines-height(2);
}

.three-lines {
  min-height: min-lines-height(3);
}
```